# Why Windows is making DLL's instead of direct Kernel Access

Tags: windows, winapi, operating-system

when developers use Windows Libraries , most of the codes are required DLL's.

We use User32.dll , Kernel32.dll , Gdi32.dll etc...

These all opened to developer's use.

These all dlls use System calls that is defined on SSDT.

Why we can't access SSDT directly ? Why microsoft added dll's as a proxy.
Whats the advantage of DLL's as proxy on core.

and as far as i know , when we call LoadLibrary function , we allocate data per process which is not 
shared.

If we want to mark it as shared , we call this pragma for datas

```
#pragma data_seg (".myseg")
```

This allows us less memory usage on DLL's.Because no process will make allocation again.

Is DLL supplying shared and unshared data across processes?
And what about CPL 0 and CPL 3 security on CPU ? is DLL used as a security layer on core ? 
DLL's is used as a Call Gates ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a practical question. How you write your program does not change based on the answer. This is more a question about operating system design. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Windows is strongly layered, kernel32.dll etc implement the winapi layer.  There were other apis, OS/2 and Posix.  The native operating system api is pretty different, resembles VMS strongly, and has changed over the years.

Comment: Voting -1 for very broad question with very problematic research effort shown and disputable usability (for anyone). If you want to learn more about internals of an Windows-like OS and get practical answers to your questions then **join the ReactOS kernel development team** at http://www.reactos.org/wiki/Welcome_to_the_ReactOS_Development_Wiki and **later-on write a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)** ;)

Comment: Not all of the API functions call directly into the kernel, many of them have user-mode components.  Using DLLs consistently gives Microsoft the flexibility to move code between user-mode and kernel-mode while maintaining backwards compatibility with existing binaries.  For example, NT 4 moved the entire Window Manager and Graphics Device Interface components from user mode to kernel mode, as [described here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windowsnt/4/workstation/reskit/en-us/archi.mspx?mfr=true).  That wouldn't have been possible if applications called the kernel directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An operating system service is invoked using an exception or interrupt of some form. This is necessary to allow the processor to change to kernel mode.

This usually has to be implemented in assembly language. The assembly code sets up the registers and stack as the system service then executes an instruction something like

CHANGE-MODE-TO-KERNEL  #100

Where 100 (my arbitrary value) is an index into the system's interrupt vector corresponding to the system service. The number would vary depend upon the system service being called.

In my simplified example, the processor hits the change mode instruction, triggers and exception, calls the interrupt routine whose address is the 100th entry in the interrupt vector. That routine is the actual system service operating in kernel mode.

This would all be a PITA (if not impossible) to do in your in C/C++/Pascal programs. An operating system usually provides wrapper functions (in DLLs in windows) that do all of this for you.

In other words, applications call a wrapper function that looks like a plain old C/C++/Pascal Function, that is written in assembly language the sets up registers and triggers the exception to move into kernel mode. The same function will unpack the registers to return any data from the system service to the calling program.